# Setting up Minecraft server to start and stop automatically

Tags: server, upstart, minecraft

I followed this tutorial: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Ubuntu_startup_script

...and I am getting an error that says:

```
start: Unknown job: minecraft-server
```

...when I run the start or stop command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upstart scripts need to end in `.conf`. To rename your file, run:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/minecraft-server /etc/init/minecraft-server.conf
```

...followed by:

```
sudo initctl reload-configuration
```